Convert DXF to GeoTIFF using GDAL
I have a DXF file with several layers with their colours, linetypes etc and I want to transform them to a GeoTIFF maintaining all the characteristics for the layers (colours, linetypes etc)
I used the following command:

gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -ts 10000 10000 'input_dxf.dxf'
output_geotiff.tif -of GTiff

however I got a TIFF with all the features rasterized in one colour (black) and also all the text existing in the DXF are gone in the GeoTIFF.
How can I rasterized the DXF keeping all the original characteristics and the text? Also, is it possible to read the size from the DXF instead of use -ts xxxx xxxxx, being xxxxx a fixed value?
I also tried with ogr2ogr, but I did not see GeoTIFF format as a possible output value.

GDAL is not really a rendering engine. The PDF driver might be the one that can preserve the styles best, but I think it would still be waste of time. Use QGIS instead.

But, how Can I import into QGIS the DXF without loose all the layer characteristics and later on export it as GeoTiff? Once I imported the DXF into Qgis, this applies Qgis styles to each feature.

Sorry, I know very little about working with DXF. There is a gap between CAD and GIS and conversions between those two worlds tend to be tricky. Perhaps some free CAD program could do better job with rendering. Or AutoCAD if you can use that.

try the QGIS Plugin "Another DXF Importer" it does a great job keeping your DXF styles. Export your QGIS Project as Raster with "Project->Import/Export -> Export Map to Raster"
